# java operator ++ problem

Tags: java, operators

I wonder why first code output is 000 while the second one is 123

first one:

```
int z=0;
    while(z<4)
    {
       z=z++;
       System.out.print(z);

    }
```

second one :

```
int z=0;
int x=0;
    while(z<5)
    {
       x=z++;
       System.out.print(x);

    }
```

what is the different between these two codes , why the first block do not increase the value of the z ?

Comment: The first code will loop forever and the second will print `01234`

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: that error stopped me from answering :(

Answer (score 13):

`z=z++` is a programmer's error -- what it does is increment z and then set z to its old value -- as a result it overwrites z with its old value and hence undoes the increment.

Comment: To be more precise, it's merely a logic error. Obviously it will compile and run just fine (although in the example provided, it will result in an infinite loop).

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the right adjective to use with the word error. ("semantic error" or "programmer error")

Answer (score 8):

The increment operator already increments `z`, you don't have to assign the return value back to `z`.

```
z++
```

Is a post increment. It returns z and AFTER that it increments z. 
In your first sample, you are basically just assigning 0 to z and your loop shouldn't end.

In your second sample, you are assigning the old value of z to x and then increment z. This means that you don't start to increment 0 again like in the first example, but when z reaches 5 (so z<5 is false), z is 5 and x is 4 because of the post increment.

Answer (score 4):

When you use the post-increment operator, you don't need to assign the result back to the variable.

That is, your code should look like this:

```
int z=0;
    while(z<4)
    {
       ++z;
       System.out.print(z);

    }
```

In Java, the operation returns the value of `z` BEFORE the increment (while incrementing the variable behind the scenes afterwards), and that value is then RE-assigned to `z`. That's why it never changes.

The pre-increment operator will do the increment and return the NEW result, so you'll get what you expect:

```
int z=0;
    while(z<4)
    {
       z=++z;
       System.out.print(z);

    }
```

This will print `1234`.

Comment: ...of course, the correct program would just do `z++;` or `++z;` and not `z=++z;`, but good illustration of the difference.

Comment: I thinks its best answer tanx

Comment: @shanky: Thanks-- if you think so, feel free to click the check mark under the voting area, on the left side of the answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

Remember this, Java evaluates your expressions **right to left** (just like C and C++),

So if your code reads

```
z = z++
```

then if z is 0 before this line is executed, what happens is:

1. `z++` is evaluated as an expression, returning the value 0
2. Then `z` is incremented because of the ++ operator, and it has the value 1.
3. Now the `z` on the left is assigned a value `z = (value returned by z++)`
4. Since the value returned by `z++` was 0, `z` is reset to 0.

The important thing to note is that the result of the assignment inherent in `z++` is evaluated *before* the `z` variable on the left is updated.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will give you a pretty good explanation.

Consider this class:

```
public class T
{
    public void f() {
    int count = 0;
    count = count++;
    }
}
```

This is the associated byte code:

```
public void f();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_1
   2:   iload_1
   3:   iinc    1, 1
   6:   istore_1
   7:   return
}
```

1. `iconst_0` loads the constant 0 onto the stack (this is for assigning the variable `count` with value `0`
2. `istore_1` stores stack value (`0` right now) into variable 1
3. `iload_1` loads int value from variable 1 (`0` right now) onto the stack
4. `zinc 1, 1` increments by `1` variable 1 (`count = 1` right now)
5. `istore_1` stores stack value (`0` right now from step #3) into variable 1
6. return

Now it should be pretty clear how `count = count++` gets compiled in Java.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are assigning the value of z with a postfix operator.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

```
int z = 0;
i = z++; // i equals 0
x = ++z; // x equals 2
```

Postfix operators will increment the value of *z* after assignment of *i*.

Unary operator `++` will increment the value of *z* before assignment of *x*.

Think of it as `++` before z as +1 before assignment, `++` after z as +1 after assignment.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but you probably ought to walk readers through what it means, in particular that the `z++` returns a value, and the assignment uses the value.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is probably better written as

```
int z=0;
while(z++<4)
{
   System.out.print(z);
}
```

or

```
int z=0;
while(z<4)
{
   z = ++z;
   System.out.print(z);
}
```

The pre-increment here is important because it will increment and then assign. Rather than assign and then increment - which has no effect other than resetting to 0 in your first example.

Since when you do `z=z++` it will reassign the old value back to `z` thus leading to an infinite loop.

The second one will end because you are not reassigning back to z:

```
int z=0;
int x=0;

while(z<5)
{
    x=z++;
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

This will print 1234.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing anything like `foo = foo++`, you're doing it wrong.  In general, if you see any expression like `x = x++ + ++x;` something is seriously wrong.  It's impossible to predict how expressions of that sort are evaluated.  In languages like `C`, such expressions can be evaluated as the implementer desires.

I'd strongly recommend playing around with the `++` operator because you're bound to encounter it when you read code.

As others have pointed out, `x++` is the postfix operator and `++x` is a prefix operator.

```
int x = 0;
int y = x++; // y=0, x=1
int z = ++x; // z=2, x=2
```

Note that the values of `y`, `z` and `x` are what they are only *after* the expression is evaluated.  What they are *during* execution is undefined.

So if you see code like `foo(x++, ++x, x)`, run for the hills.

Your own problem is more succinctly written:

```
for (int z=0; z<4; ++z) {
    System.out.print(z);
}
```

The above code has the advantage that the variable `z` is scoped within the `for` loop, so it won't accidentally collide with some other variable.

Answer (score -1):

```
z=z++;
```

This means first assign the value of z (which is in right position) to the z (which in left position), then do the increment in right z (which is of no use).

Comment: Its simple written in one line, so that user can understand easily. But I think its confusing you, so you should do an exercise and learn.

Comment: Its simple written in one line, so that user can understand easily. But I think its confusing you, so you should do an exercise and learn. 

The above comment is for 'Duncan'.

Comment: @Duncan: If there is nothing new that doesn't means you should downvote and answer is also not wrong. So I would recommend you to don't be over smart always, and you should read and understand.

Comment: @Duncan: If you want to be a good man, you should be a good listener and reader, but you are not. You are over-confident and always under-estimate others. (That you proved). I hope you will understand this one day. 
Good Day & Good Bye