# ++ operator in java

Tags: java, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java operator ++ problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945707/java-operator-problem)

This is the code. I know the difference between c++ and ++c.

```
public class sample {
  public static void main(String[] b){
    int count = 0,a=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      count=count++;
      System.out.println(count);
    }
```

But what I am expecting is

```
count=count;count=count+1;//output has to be 1  2 3
```

but the output is 0 0 0.

Comment: +1 Ouch, that's a nasty thing you have there.

Comment: I am trying to understand the concepts not for implementation...

Answer (score 15):

Your prediction is wrong.

count++ will increment count by 1 and return the old value (0). Which is your case. Afterwards, you assign the old value (0) to your `count` variable. To make it more understandable, just look at this code

```
count = count; // is the same as count = count++;
```

Don't use `count = count++;`, just use `count++`

Answer (score 6):

In Java, this code is guaranteed to keep the variable with the same value.

It's like:

```
int temp;
temp = count;
count = count +1;
count = temp;
```

to acheieve what you want, write:

```
count++; //or
count += 1; //or
count = count +1;
```

Comment: @freshdroid this is what you seek.

Comment: so in both c=a++ and c=++a increment will be done first. But the difference is c will be given old value in first case and updated value in second .. am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `count=count++;` with `count++;` .

Answer (score 2):

```
count = count ++;
```

Here's what is happening.

First, `count++` is evaluated, which evaluated to 0, but increments `count`. And this `0` is assigned to count. So count remains 0. The following is different, because ++count evaluates to 1, 2...

```
count = ++count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified your code and I have made it to work

```
public class sample {
    public static void main(String[] b){
        int count = 0,a=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

You don't have to reassign the value of count++ to count. Java will do it for you. I added some parentheses which were missing in your code. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you a pretty good explanation.

Consider this class:

```
public class T
{
    public void f() {
    int count = 0;
    count = count++;
    }
}
```

This is the associated byte code:

```
public void f();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_1
   2:   iload_1
   3:   iinc    1, 1
   6:   istore_1
   7:   return
}
```

1. `iconst_0` loads the constant 0 onto the stack (this is for assigning the variable `count` with value `0`
2. `istore_1` stores stack value (`0` right now) into variable 1
3. `iload_1` loads int value from variable 1 (`0` right now) onto the stack
4. `zinc 1, 1` increments by `1` variable 1 (`count = 1` right now)
5. `istore_1` stores stack value (`0` right now from step #3) into variable 1
6. return

Now it should be pretty clear how `count = count++` gets compiled in Java.